# How does setTimeout work regarding the window origin and context in JavaScript/TypeScript? (closing tab using window.close() function)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I recently worked on a project that used React to create a simple site. An Iframe on another domain was called for the user to take some photos and send them to a database, and close the Iframe. On mobile, because of various limitations (like on iOS), instead of an Iframe, a new tab was opened for the photos to be taken. The returning to the original site was done by a Back button on the Iframe and on the new tab, once the pthotos were taken.

I had to make the Back button work on the new opened tab. Taking the photos meant following some steps, which created history on the new tab's window. I tried many ways, using BroadcastChannel, postMessage and localStorage, to try to communicate to the original site (which, I said, was on another domain), to tell it to close the window, with no success. Having history in tab's window meant that the `window.close()` function, called from the tab, worked only in the first step, immediately after opening the new tab.

After trying for some weeks with no success, I asked a senior JS programmer to help.

His solution, which works, baffled me:

Inside the function that is called on the click event of the Back button, he put the following code:

```
function backOnClick() {
    //some code
    if (onMobile) {
        setTimeout(() => window.close(), 200)
        return
    }
    //some more code
}
```

Why does this works, but calling the `window.close()` directly (without setTimeout function) does not?

Does it have to do something with context, or is the thread that setTimeout executes on has no history associated with it? I understand why the other solutions failed, but I would really like to know why this works.

I hope his solution helps someone who is looking to close a tab in web browser, and having trouble with it.
Hats down to the senior developers. I stand in awe every time I witness them solving problems. Cheers!

EDIT:

I think I understand what happens, after discussing the matter with some other `js` programmers.  The function `backOnClick()` is executed at server side, and the server cannot close the client's windows. By putting the `close` statement in the `setTimeout()` function, the server gives the closing job to the client, who can close it's own windows.

Hope this helps someone to understand the mechanisms behind the scenes better.

Comment: Not sure to understand your situation, could you please try to make a repro? I tried doing one, but calling `window.close()` from a redirection works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/jghUmzPzu5HcJzAE Also, even on cross-domain pages you can call `top.postMessage` or `opener.postMessage` in iframe and opened window respectively.

Comment: cannot be sure without looking into related code, but `setTimeout` is often used like this to make sure code runs after few microseconds in situations where 2 or more things are happening at the same time.

Comment: To Kaiido: `window.close()` did not work if I had history (navigating through the steps of picture taking process). On the other hand, when calling top.postMessage and opener.postMessage, I got the error cannot access top / opener object.

Comment: To Jashwant: I understand what `setTimeout` does. I'm curios how this function relates to other entities/objects, like window, context, domain. Why the `window.close()` did not work when called directly, but worked when called from `setTimeout` callback function?